# Обязателен ли пробел между цифрой и «%»?

Tags: пробелы, цифры, знак-процента

Обязательно ли всегда писать, например, `100 %`, а не `100%`? Грамота писала, что пробелы нужны, и в одном учебнике я видел с пробелами. Однако в двух других пробелов не было. Пробел, ясное дело, ставить можно (и, возможно, даже нужно), но можно ли пробел не писать? Интересно узнать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы видели разное написание, с пробелом и без, потому что правила менялись

> В русском языке в течение многих десятилетий существует традиция не
> отбивать (то есть не отделять пробелом) знак процента от последней
> цифры числа, к которому он относится, в отличие от обозначений прочих
> единиц и аналогично обозначению градусов, минут и секунд. Эта традиция
> отражена в справочнике М. В. Шульмейстера (1967).
> Вероятно, эта традиция объясняется тем, что процент можно считать не
> обозначением единицы измерения, а математическим знаком, обозначающим
> сотую долю, то есть обозначения «1%», «0,01», «10−2», «0,00(9)» — это
> просто разная запись одного и того же числа.

Смотрим далее:

> В 1982 г. введён в действие ГОСТ 8.417—81, в соответствии с которым
> знак процента следует писать по тем же правилам, что и обозначения
> остальных единиц, то есть между последней цифрой числа и обозначением
> единицы следует оставлять пробел.

Ориентиемся на самое позднее:

> Правило, введённое ГОСТ 8.417—81, в советское время не стало
> общепризнанным. Уже после введения этого ГОСТа были изданы справочники
> В. А. Вигдорчика (1985) и П. Г. Гиленсона (1988), в которых
> по-прежнему рекомендовалось придерживаться традиционных правил набора
> и не отбивать знак процента.

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82,%2C%2010%25%20%D0%B8%2015%25.)**

Comment: Кста-ати, а сейчас как? Сейчас отбивать или нет? Или оба можно? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: "Ориентиемся на самое позднее..." Не отбивать.

Comment: Спасибо! Жаль, а мне нравилось с пробелом больше. Но я всë-таки буду делать, как надо по правилам.

Comment: Максимка! Делай как красче! К языку это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Галина, так дальше по вашей ссылке есть ещё справочник Мильчина (наиболее авторитетный), в котором знак процента рекомендуется отбивать пробелом, и год 1998-й. Ну и Грамота в своих ответах пишет об этом же. Другое дело, что эта рекомендация сплошь и рядом не соблюдается...

Comment: Я ж грю: это не язык, нужно рисовать - глаз радовать!